# How to output mathematical operation alongside the calculation in simple Kotlin Calculator

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, output, concatenation

I'm very new to Kotlin programming and can't seem to figure out a working solution. I need to have the output include the mathematical operation and have it equal the calculation as the output
eg. 1+1=2 needs to be the output instead of just the answer
My addition function is below
Any help if greatly appreciated.

```
fun add(){
        var input1 = firstvalue.text.toString().trim().toBigDecimal()
        var input2 = secondvalue.text.toString().trim().toBigDecimal()
        calcoutput.text = input1.add(input2).toString()
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a good time to learn about [string templates](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/strings.html#string-templates)!

You can add the value of a variable to a string like this:

```
val name = "Wuffles"
println("My dog's name is $name")
```

That will call `toString()` on the variable and add the result into the final string. If you need to access anything more complicated than a basic variable name, e.g. a property on a thing, or even the result of some code, you wrap it in `{}` so you end up with `${something}`:

```
println("First input: ${firstValue.text}")
println("Result: ${input1 + input2}")
```

So what you're basically doing is creating a string with some fixed text, and some places where you insert a value. See if you can work out how to create the string `"1 + 1 = 2"` except with the correct values inserted!

Comment: Thank you. Because of people like you, I feel like I'm learning more and more everyday! A true hero!